# Using Quick Settings Tile API in older Android versions

Tags: android

I want to create a main menu in my android application, where I can edit, delete, and add tiles (with icons).
I have came across `Quick Settings Tile API` which is new to me. So I want to know if I can use it in older Android versions. If no, is there any alternatives to that? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to add tiles to your app or use your app to add tiles to quick settings?

Comment: "So I want to know if I can use it in older Android versions" -- no. "is there any alternatives to that?" -- please explain **in detail** what an "alternative" would be like. Android has activities, app widgets, notifications, etc.

Comment: @RoystonPinto I want to add tiles to my app.

Comment: Then you will need to define your own layouts, Quick Setting Tile API will not be useful for you.